# Making a filler with google chrome extension: Uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a google chrome extension that fills out a google forms, but I keep on getting an error for addEventListener.
My project is based on the [tutorial here](http://www.mwtestconsultancy.co.uk/automated-form-filler/):

Here is my code and thanks for the help!
html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>  
    <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>

    </script><script src="popup.js"></script>

    </head>
  <body>
    <h2>filler</h2>
    <button id="fillForm">Fill form</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript Main

```
document.getElementById('fillForm').addEventListener('click', function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: "injector.js"
    });
});
```

Injector.js

```
var placeholder = document.querySelectorAll('.exportLabel');

placeholder[1].remove();
document.querySelector('input[aria-label="Name"]').value = 'Mark Winteringham';
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I get:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at popup.js:1

Comment: what do you mean main? can you add your manifest.json file? looks like the script can't access the dom. ( as `document.getElementById('fillForm')` returns `null`)

Comment: Simply move the script tag to the end of popup.html before the closing body tag.